# "Дружный сплоченный коллектив" — нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Как вы считаете, нужна ли запятая в словосочетании *дружный сплоченный коллектив*?
Это однородные члены или нет?

Answer (score 3):

Запятая нужна, это однородные прилагательные, раскрывают тему доверительных отношений в коллективе независимо друг от друга: **дружный, сплоченный коллектив.**

Однородные прилагательные по значению часто бывают  **близки к синонимам** (мы как бы подбираем подходящие слова для раскрытия данной темы).

В случае неоднородных отношений прилагательное "дружный" должно определять сочетание "сплоченный коллектив", но это не так: сплоченный коллектив  всегда бывает дружным.